# How to launch Trello on Login as menubar item?

Tags: catalina, startup, menu-bar, login-items, trello

Is there a way to launch **Trello** app on Login or startup, in `menubar only` state.

**Menubar only state :**
There's a `window style` dropdown option in Trello settings. When you choose `Dock & Menubar extra`, a Trello icon appears in the menubar which can be used to toggle the visibility of the app window *(show/hide)* by clicking on it. While in the *hidden* state, only the menubar icon and the dock indicator is visible.

**In short :** How to launch `Trello` on startup in *hidden* visibility state?

*macos v10.15.3*
*Trello v2.11.4*

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Go to the Trello App and click on Preferences. Clicking preferences brings up a pane as shown below.

[image]

Under the phrase Window Style click on the pull-down menu arrow showing the pane below.

[image]

Click o menu only to have Trello show as a menu icon only.

Now you need to get it to start on login or restart. To do this go to system preferences under the Apple menu item. Click on the "User & Groups" preference pane. When that panel appears, be sure to click on the tab "Login Items". This displays a listing of items started on Login. Be sure to unlock the panel and click on the + button at bottom of the list. This allows you to add an app to start at login. After clicking the + button locate Trello and select it. This tells Trello to start at login. See image below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think you missed a point or maybe it's not working, just on my end. Following your solution, the Trello **Window** opens up at startup. So it's not actually in the hidden state. While when you click on the menubar icon, it goes to the hidden state.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is quite not possible right now. But you can get pretty close. Though not much convincing, still it's a workaround *(not for all cases)*.

So I used the good old `Automator` to build an app which has just one action in the workflow :- `Watch Me Do`
Then I recorded my actions which were as follows:

- Open Trello
- Click on the `Trello Icon` in the menu bar(located on the right side)

Increase the playback speed and the `Automator` will do it in no time.

Finally, to start your new app, add it to the `login items` as described by `@jmh`'s answer.

[How to perform `Automator`'s `Watch Me Do`?](https://youtu.be/x3dxfpQ8KGY?t=105)

There will be certain cases where this solution might not work. For example: if multiple app icon's are displayed in the menu bar at startup, then the `Automator`'s `Watch Me Do` might end up clicking at the wrong location.

> **Tip:** While recording for `Watch Me Do`, give a pause between opening the app and clicking the menu bar icon, as the app might take more time to open at startup